# DataTables 'crash' with more than 1 entry: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables to display the sent contact messages.

When there is only 1 message in my database table the plug-in works perfectly fine, but right when there is another message sent, the following  error appears in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

As far as it seems I have my table HTML layout fine so what is going wrong?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @if(isset($messages))
            @foreach($messages as $message)
                <td>{{$message->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$message->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$message->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$message->subject}}</td>
                <td>{{$message->message}}</td>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = Message::all();

    return view('admin.messages.index', compact('messages'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `<tr>` element into the loop.

```html
@if(isset($messages))
     @foreach($messages as $message)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$message->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$message->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$message->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$message->subject}}</td>
            <td>{{$message->message}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```